# Flutter Firestore add Map inside of Array

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

in my flutter app I want to add firestore new arrays with map style like this :

[image]

but I couldn't. I am using this function for add array but its not working like that. this code adding array like that, for example:

[image]

How can I change this code for adding array like picture one?

```
void addData2() {
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user = auth.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;

var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
map['doOne'] = do1TextEditingController.text ;
map['doTwo'] = do2TextEditingController.text ;


FirebaseFirestore.instance.
collection('users').
doc(uid).
set({

  "arrayData": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
    map['doOne'],
    map['doTwo']

  ])

},SetOptions(merge: true)

).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});

setState(() {
  isLoadingThree = false;
});

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new field that's an array, just pass the array.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.
collection('users').
doc(uid).
set({
  "arrayData": [ map ]
},SetOptions(merge: true)
```

That will create an arry with one item.  Simply add more map items in the array in square brackets if you need more.

`FieldValue.arrayUnion()` is used only when you need to add more items to an existing array field.

Comment: "arrayData": FieldValue.arrayUnion([ map ])  I changed the codes like this, this is exacly what I need :D

Comment: When I try to add a new item in that list it just wipes the list and puts only the item that pushed last how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you need to pass an object to the `arrayUnion` method in order to be able to create maps in the firebase. You are currently passing just values which is why it's creating an array of values. The working example would be like that:

```dart
// my code
var yourObject = new Map<String, dynamic>();

yourObject["one"] = 1;
yourObject["two"] = 2;
yourObject["three"] = false;
yourObject["four"] = "text";
yourObject["five"] = [
  1,2,3,4
];
yourObject["six"] = [
  {
    "nestedOne": 1,
    "nestedTwo": false,
  },
  {
    "nestedThree": 2,
    "nestedFour": true,
  },
];

var encodedObject = json.encode(yourObject);

print(encodedObject);

// your code
FirebaseFirestore.instance.
collection('users').
doc(uid).
set({

  "arrayData": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
    encodedObject 
  ])

},SetOptions(merge: true)

).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
```

It's better, however, to create a `Class` for your firebase document model and create methods `toMap()` and a named constructor `ClassName.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json)` to be able to convert Cloud Firestore data to your objects and convert those objects to Firestore models.

Comment: You mean you don't know what json is or you don't know the fields you will receive?