# Add data from flutter to firestore with array format

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Currently my flutter code is adding data to firestore in a Map type like image 1.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R87Oc.png)
However, I would want it to add data to firestore in a array type like image 2.
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19X3E.png)
This is the code for adding the clicked item to firestore database in Map type(Image 3)
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ1as.png)

Comment: Try adding the variable `_items` directly to the firestore ie. don't convert it to map

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you would want to add something similar to an Array of Maps to Firestore. Based on this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65237396/), it is doable without much effort. I have confirmed that it works on my test Firestore and used the following code:

```
//Adding new array of maps

Map<String, dynamic> user1 = {"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Smith"};
Map<String, dynamic> user2 = {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"};

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
firestore
  .collection('testMapArray')
  .doc('test1')
  .update({
    'array1': [user1, user2]
  })
  .then((value) => print("Updated"))
  .catchError((error) => print("Failed"));
```

This is how it looks inside the Firestore browser:

[image]

You can also make use of the `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` [function](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue-class.html) to append additional values to the array without altering the existing values:

```
 //Adding additional elements to the array of maps

  Map<String, dynamic> user1 = {"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Smith"};
  Map<String, dynamic> user2 = {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"};
  Map<String, dynamic> user3 = {"firstName": "Foo", "lastName": "Bar"};

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  firestore
      .collection('testMapArray')
      .doc('test1')
      .update({
        'array1': FieldValue.arrayUnion([user3])
      })
      .then((value) => print("Updated"))
      .catchError((error) => print("Failed"));
```

This snippet only adds the third user to the existing Array of Maps:

[image]

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can click on the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted. This can help future users who are having the same issue.

Comment: Works perfeclty.